# Is there a way, using sftp, to copy a file on a remote file system to the same file system?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Is there a way, using sftp, to copy a file on a remote file system to the same file system?

What this means is 
`user@hostname:/path/file.txt` to `user@hostname:/path/copy_of_file.txt` from a remote machine?  I am doing remote testing and need to copy some large files on the remote system with out mirroring the file to or from the test system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most SFTP servers do not support duplication of a remote file.

There's [`copy-file` extension to SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00#section-6). But it's supported by few SFTP servers only. For example by [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise WinSSHD. The most widespread SFTP server, the OpenSSH supports related `copy-data` only in very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0).

---

Quite often, when you have an SFTP access, you also have an SSH shell access. Then you can copy the files using shell commands (like `cp` in *nix).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer is no: the ftp/sftp protocol does not allow an offloaded remote copy.

Comment: There's [`copy-file` extension to SFTP protocol](http://serverfault.com/a/724205/168875).

Comment: Yes, but it is an _extension_ of the core protocol. And a quite rare one...

Answer (score 1):

Not really "using sftp", but since sftp uses SSH, can't you just log on the remote server using ssh, and copy your file normally ?

Another alternative I would consider would be using sshfs, which lets you mount your ssh dir as a virtual drive, and use commands like cp on it.  I'm not sure about the performance, but it can be worth trying.
This works even if your shell is disabled with something like `/bin/false`, which can be pretty handy.

Comment: Some cloud providers only give you access via sftp and/or rsync and won't allow you to login via ssh. cdn77 does that. That's why such questions arise.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by previous answers, the protocol does not support what you need.
You can work around this by downloading the file, renaming the downloaded copy on your own machine, and then upload it again. This is bulky, but if done as a part of an sftp script it does not really matter.

```
get file.txt
!mv file.txt copy_of_file.txt
put copy_of_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but the problem was to reduce the overhead of moving files that are 30 GB+.  I worked around the problem by a combination of ssh as well as sftp commands.

Comment: Well, it consumes significant amout of resourses both in terms of network traffic and io.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had a similar problem and found your answer online.
Even tough the thread is quite old I still want to share my answer.

I also did not find a solution to solve that problem with boardtools but there is some third-party software which does the trick quite well from sysax.com.
They have a automation software to create a script, which can handle SFTP and other protocols.

Answer (score -1):

sftp uses for source or destination the local file system. So, short answer, no.

Comment: Well for some reason sftp does enable you to remove and rename remote files for instance. But not copy them and not move between dirs. Unless you download and then upload.